# My software getting crashed due to "getdiskserial.dll"

Tags: windows, crash, windows-server-2012, dll

I am using Windows server 2012 on our intranet server. One of important application is not opening. When I double click on the application icon, Windows show an msg *"Application has stopped working,Check online online for solution and Close the program"* 
When I click show problem details, I can found the problem is due to  **getdiskserial.dll** 
Software vendor say **getdiskserial.dll**  is missing form your OS.

If the problem is due to that dll file

1. Where can I saftly download that dll file?
2. Is there any other solution to rectify the problem?

Answer (score 0):

`getdiskserial.dll` is not a dll that comes with windows. The software vendor likely ment you need to re-install their software so it will register the necessary dll's

Comment: I tried reinstalltion of the software but the no use of that :(

Comment: Then I would call the vendor again and ask them where you should be getting that DLL from, because it is not dll that comes with windows, either part of their software or part of some 3rd party library they rely on.